# Adding an conditional to create object with a TypeScript loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I have this loop in my code that is essentially taking an array of dates (dates) and adding each one as a key/value pair ("date":"dates[i]") to each object in my array (values).

```
  values.forEach((obj, i) => obj.date = dates[i]);
```

The problem is, some of the places in my 'values' array are 'null' and I receive a 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'date' of null.'

How can I adjust for this? Is there a way using TypeScript to include a catch/conditional for those 'null' values, and to replace them with a new object containing that ("date":"dates[i]") key/value pair?

something like:

```
values.forEach((obj, i) => 

    if (values[i]==null){
        values[i]=={}
        values[i].date == dates[i]
       }
    else {
        obj.date = dates[i]
       }
);
```

If it matters, I'm using Angular 5 components to write this to technically they are this.values and this.dates.

I'm having trouble figuring this out. Thank you!!

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes it did! Sorry I forgot to respond, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you want can be achieved by:

```
values = values.map((obj, i) => {
 if (!obj) {
   return {date: dates[i]};
 }
 obj.date = dates[i];
 return obj;
});
```

In this situation, Array.map is more appropriate than Array.forEach, beacuse you mean to make changes to the objects on the array (Array.map returns a new object for the position at each iteration, returning a new array at the end of all the iterations).

If you use Array.forEach, you can change some property of some existing object inside your array, but you can't make something like:

```
values.forEach((obj, i) => {
 if (!obj) {
   obj = {date: dates[i]};
 }
 obj.date = dates[i];
});
```

The code inside the 'if' won't have the desired effect (the obj inside the array will be continuing to be null), as each object is merely referencing the corresponding element inside the array.